# Parse Website Data in C++

Tags: c++, html, parsing, variables, web

So I am trying to develop a program that will parse a website for data, send that data into variable that I can then use for functions inside the program.

Specifically I'm trying to parse this page (Click the debuffs tab)

> `http://worldoflogs.com/reports/rt-1smdoscr7neq0k6b/spell/94075/`

The source is pretty simple and looks like this.

```
    <td><a href='/reports/rt-1smdoscr7neq0k6b/details/62/' class='actor'><span class='Warrior'>Zonnza</span></a></td>
    <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href='/reports/rt-1smdoscr7neq0k6b/details/3/' class='actor'><span class='DeathKnight'>Fillzholez</span></a></td>
    <td>89</td>
</tr>
```

While I only want the numbers and name, ex what is between `<td></td>` and between the `<span class=''></span>` tags. Is there anyway to do what I'm looking for?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look into [Tag Soup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/).  It's a parser for HTML that can cope with all the horrible HTML that's out there.  There's a [C++ port](http://www.jezuk.co.uk/cgi-bin/view/arabica/log?id=3591) of it available too (haven't used that so can't comment on how stable it is).

Answer (score 1):

There are no C++ libraries for what you're trying to do (unless you're going to link with a half of Mozilla or WebKit), but you can consider using Java with [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

And for those suggesting regular expressions, an obligatory [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use C++, when C-style sscanf will do, or even `perl` or any language with regular expression support.

Comment: I'm looking to specifically use C++ or possibly c# as those are the only actual programming languages that I know.

Comment: @Cistoran, it is not a valid reason for choosing a language. Better select languages on libraries availability. But if you're ok with C#, you can use HTMLUnit with iKVM, at least it works for me.

Comment: @SK-Logic I'm not saying it is, but those are the only languages I've had a chance/opportunity to learn thus far.

Comment: @Cistoran, Java is almost a subset of C#, so you won't have any troubles using it.

Comment: @SK-logic I'm already using the Tag-Soup port for C++ but thanks.

Comment: @Cistoran, HTMLunit is much more robust - it allows you to extract data from AJAX pages too. The only way to extract data properly from the modern web-pages is to simulate a full-blown browser, no simple parsing will be generic enough.

Comment: There's no need to use C, or C++, or even `perl` input when there are existing libraries and utilities out there.